# How to excute sql agent job on azure vm without connecting to virtual machine

Tags: sql-server

I have one virtual machine(vm) in microsoft azure.I have SQL Server 2016 standard edition.I created SQL scheduled job in vm and this job is running successfully when I connect and login to vm. But my requirement is that I need to start vm automatically and without login to vm my scheduled job needs to be run. My vm is started automatically but after auto start VM my job is not running.

Please give me suggestion
Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the SQL Server Agent service on the VM set to start automatically. When the VM and service are running, the SQL Server Agent service will run jobs according to the specified job schedule.

Comment: SQL Server Agent Service was setup to start automatically. I am not sure about what I am missing.

Comment: @Pratik, do you have a time-based schedule defined for the job? The job should run at the scheduled time as long as the VM and SQL Server Agent are running even if no one is logged in.